# Nothing happens when baking fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

Blender File: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/f5t132aukwqmg0l/AADiffjRgnVy7CMPK-VkSs7Va?dl=0

I'm attempting something similar to this (https://youtu.be/Gk0uhBcLknQ?t=6m24s) (link should start at what I'm attempting to create).

What I'm trying to do so far is do a simple bake so I can experiment with how the water will flow and set obstacle setting afterwards. However, baking does absolutely nothing.

I've looked around many sites and I can't seem to find an answer. I've tried deleting the cache files and going with advice that has been given to others with similar issues, but nothing appears to work.

Comment: Read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale to domain and inflow object. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Why is there an inverted sphere in the inflow? Remove it, it is going to give us some wrong direction otherwise.

And finally, your domain is very large compared to the preview resolution of 45. The inflow is so small that the emitted fluid is not visible.

Voxels (volume elements) are the smallest unit in the volumetric fluid simulation. Since the emitted fluid is smaller than a voxel, no geometry is created.

To solve this:

1. Scale up the inflow.
2. Scale down the domain.
3. Apply scale.
4. Increase the resolution.
5. Immediately switch to final resolution under viewport display. This is going to show us the final resoluted geometry.

Here are some more efficient scale at a final resolution of 200. Note how to domain will barely contain all of the fluid.

[image]